# Как сверстать такую плитку на Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Каким образом сверстать такие плитки на Bootstrap 3 ?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сложность вызвал горчичный фон поверх картинки с текстом.

Вот такая разметка у меня сейчас:

```css
.items {
 margin-top: 25px;
}

.name-item {
 font-weight: bold;
 background: #c19f50;
 color: #fff;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row items">

     <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 item">
      <img class="img-responsive col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" src="https://apisplus.by/radik/images/item-1.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="name-item col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">Парикмахерские услуги</div>
     </div>

     <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 item">
      <img class="img-responsive col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" src="https://apisplus.by/radik/images/item-1.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="name-item col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">Парикмахерские услуги</div>
     </div>

     <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 item">
      <img class="img-responsive col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" src="https://apisplus.by/radik/images/item-1.jpg" alt="">
      <div class="name-item col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">Парикмахерские услуги</div>
     </div>

    </div>

   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

С помощью `position: absolute`

```css
.items {
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.name-item {
  font-weight: bold;
  background: #c19f50;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.item_inner {
display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.name-item {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row items">

  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 item">
  <div class="item_inner">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="https://apisplus.by/radik/images/item-1.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="name-item">Парикмахерские услуги</div>
  </div></div>



</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так. Вам нужно обратить внимание только на позиционирование "position: relative;" и "position: absolute;". Вообще с появлением flex и grid bootstrap как таковой не нужен, только мешается иногда перебивая личные стили. Ну и не ставьте везде прям col, например изображению и тексту они вообще не нужны, так как вы везде указали col-12, а это 100%. У элементов по умолчанию 100% от их размера.
Переходите уже на Bootstrap 5, раз только учитесь.
Хотел применить классовое позиционирование, но оно оказывается поддерживается с bootstrap 4.

```css
.items {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 20px;
}
.item {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.item .name-item {
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #c19f50;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: -100px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
.item:hover .name-item {
  bottom: 0;
}
img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="row items">

  <div class="item">
    <img class="" src="https://apisplus.by/radik/images/item-1.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="name-item">Парикмахерские услуги</div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img class="" src="https://apisplus.by/radik/images/item-1.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="name-item">Парикмахерские услуги</div>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img class="" src="https://apisplus.by/radik/images/item-1.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="name-item">Парикмахерские услуги</div>
  </div>

</div>
```